# Sitecore User Group Oct 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are wicked excited to announce the Oct'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

THE QUESTION OF MORAL ALGORITHMS by Ishraq Al Fataftah, four time Sitecore MVP and the CTO at Applez Tech

Automating the conversion from Web Forms for Marketers (WFFM) to Sitecore 9 Forms by Alessandro Faniuolo, Principal Developer on the Production Support team at Velir

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Oct, 02, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Oct, 02, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click her](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/265188991/)e for more details and RSVP.